# SQL Query Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to select from two tables using join and then grouping by type. How do I escape 'active'?

It's throwing this error on Query window (management studio):

**Error**

```
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 
Ambiguous column name 'active'. 
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 
Invalid column name 'zone'.
```

**Query**

```
select 
vendor.name,type_zone.type as zone
from dbo.vendor join dbo.type_zone
on fkType_zoneID = pkType_ZoneID 
where active = 1
GROUP BY zone
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errors mean that the "active" column name exists in both tables. You need to specify it as `type_zone.active` or `vendor.active` in your tests, to identify which table should have its column of that name tested.

Your `GROUP BY` clause is flawed because you have no aggregate function in your `SELECT` clause.

Comment: How could I Implement Group By?

Comment: Why are you trying to group? Are you trying to obtain an aggregate? Or do you have duplicates for some reason?

Comment: In the query, vendors are matched to a zone, need to group them by zone I though. I've used the wrong operator, I think ORDER BY did the trick i was looking. No aggregation used...

Comment: Yes, `ORDER BY` is what you're looking for. `GROUP BY` is used for giving sums or averages per date, or counts of records by geographical area, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Qualify the active column with a tablename:

`vendor.active` or `type_zone.active`

(I'm not sure which of those tables the active column refers to.  That's why the server gives you the error; it can't tell either.)

Answer (score 1):

The column `active` appears in both tables.  You need to identify which `active` column you want to use.  For example

```
WHERE vendor.active = 1
```

You can't use the column alias in the GROUP BY clause.  Change `zone` to `type_zone.type`

Answer (score 0):

It depend s on which table active is in.  If it is in vendor, then the following should work:

```
select 
vendor.name,type_zone.type as zone
from dbo.vendor inner join dbo.type_zone
on fkType_zoneID = pkType_ZoneID 
where dbo.vendor.active = 1
GROUP BY type_zone.type
```

It is easier to deal with this if you alias your tables, as in the following:

```
select 
v.name,t.type as zone
from dbo.vendor v inner join dbo.type_zone t
on v.fkType_zoneID = t.pkType_ZoneID 
where v.active = 1
GROUP BY t.type
```